# Command line produces a beep even with sound off - how do I stop it

Tags: windows-xp, command-line

I have noticed that sometimes a command window can generate a beep, even if the sounds is turned off.  Can I stop this ?

This is rather embarrassing in a library where you are meant to have the computer on silent.

Comment: Thank you for this, chaps. I make many many mistakes and the noise was driving me round the beeping bend.

Answer (score 2):

To silence the current session:

```
net stop beep
```

To silence for good:

```
sc config beep start= disabled
```

More information:
http://blog.tiensivu.com/aaron/archives/1436-One-liners-Disable-the-PC-Speaker-beeps-in-200xXPVista.html

Comment: looks useful but I get permission errors.  how can I run ad Administrator?

Comment: runas /user:localmachinename\administrator cmd

Comment: http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/runas.mspx?mfr=true